# Finding time in a range of hours

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am struggling to find an effective, and clear, algorithm to solve the following problem. I am specifically working in javascript, but it is really a pretty generalized problem.

I have a store open for a number of hours each day
Sun: closed
Mon: 7a-6p
Tues: 7a-6p
...

Each day can have a different set of operating hours and some days may be closed entirely.

If This store does work that takes a certain number of hours, and only does work during its operating hours. How can I calculate the earliest time something will be done? A couple of considerations, some work might take more than a week of operating hours to complete, and the store might choose to close at some more random time, 6:03.

Comment: So the working times repeat every week, or would we need to consider a complete calendar?

Comment: Can daylight savings adjustments fall during store work hours or is there always the same number of hours in a workday for a given store on a given day of the week (modulo "some days may be closed entirely")?

Comment: @Bergi Yes the working times are set on a week basis and repeat.

Comment: @MikeSamuel For this particular application I don't need to worry about daylights savings time being during the working hours. It is in theory possible, but is an edge case I am not remotely concerned with at the moment.

Comment: @NikolaB - I can't paste the current solution unfortunately, but essentially it tries to count up days by seeing the remaining milliseconds to work in the day, and then adding a day if there is more time remaining. It repeats until it finds the end. Problem is it is very difficult to follow.

Comment: @Matt: If you have code, you should post it. We can help you to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? You'd need to have really long jobs for it to cause any performance issues.

```
var timeToFinish = getTimeToFinish(job);
var timeLeft = timeToFinish;
var date = getStartingDate(job);

while(timeLeft > 0){

    var workingHours = getWorkingHours(day);

    if(timeLeft > workingHours){
        timeLeft -= workingHours;
        date = nextDay(date);
    } else {
        timeLeft == 0;
    }

}

return date;
```

Where the function `getWorkingHours(day)` probably would consult a database that has the schedule of opening times.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param hoursOfWork a non-negative number of hours required to complete
 *     a project.
 * @param openHours A list of length 7 of lists of ranges of
 *     inclusive hours in the range [0-23].
 *     For a particular day of the week,
 *     open 9-5 is represented by [[9,17]],
 *     and closed-for-the-day is represented by [],
 *     and open 9-12 and 1-5 is represented by [[9, 12], [13, 17]].
 * @param startDayOfWeek is an integer in the range [0, 6] of the first
 *     day of the week on which work occurs.
 */
function daysRequired(hoursOfWork, startDayOfWeek, openHours) {
  var daysInWeek = 7;  // Vive la revolution (but not metric weeks).

  // Make sure they're open sometime during the week so we don't infinitely loop.
  var totalForWeek = 0;
  var totalsForDay = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < daysInWeek; ++i) {
    var hoursOfWorkInDay = hoursOfWork[i];
    var totalForDay = 0;
    for (var j = 0, n = hoursOfWorkInDay.length; j < n; ++j) {
      totalForDay += (hoursOfWorkInDay[j][1] - hoursOfWorkInDay[j][0]);
    }
    totalForWeek += totalForDay;
    totalsForDay[i] = totalForDay;
  }
  if (totalForWeek < 1) { throw new Error('work harder'); }
  if (hoursOfWork !== hoursOfWork || !isFinite(hoursOfWork)) {
    throw new Error('' + hoursOfWork);
  }

  // Step forward by days subtracting each days work hours from the total.
  var daysRequired = 0;
  var dayOfWeek = startDayOfWeek;
  while (hoursOfWork > 0) {
    ++daysRequired;  // Count the day since we have to do some work on it.
    var totalForDay = totalsForDay[dayOfWeek];
    if (totalForDay >= hoursOfWork) { break; }
    hoursOfWork -= totalForDay;  // Work that day.
    dayOfWeek = (dayOfWeek + 1) % daysInWeek;  // Skip to next day of week.
  }
  return daysRequired;
}
```